# Comparison of two CI/CD strategies with k8s deployment previews

Tags: kubernetes, cicd, github-actions

I am implementing a new CI/CD strategy across my organization's several dozen repos.

The main goal is to move from a dedicated QA environment branch to deployment previews in ad-hoc environments created in a Kubernetes cluster, allowing features to be released unilaterally and without risk of blocking one another.

There are 2 strategies I'm looking into.

What are the pros, cons, and possible pitfalls of each?

Are there amendments to either strategy that could strengthen them, or accepted best practices I could take into account?

### Strategy 1: Single CI/CD pipeline, deploy with Github Environment Deployment

1. Developers create features branches from `main`
2. When ready, developers create a pull request from their feature branch back into `main`
3. On `pull_request` triggers, Github Actions runs a single pipeline that executes each of these jobs in succession:

   1. Runs CI checks (linting, static analysis, unit tests)
   2. Runs a [Github Environment Deployment](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment) to an environment named after the branch, which doesn't need approval and does the following:

      1. Creates and applies a patch with `git diff --cherry main...feature` (without committing), putting the code in an "as if it were merged into main" state.
      2. Builds and publishes an image with the patched code, tagged with the branch name
      3. Creates a k8s manifest for a new environment named after the branch, containing the new image
      4. Deploys the new k8s manifest, creating an environment available at `{branch-name}.example.com`.
   3. Runs functional tests and dynamic analysis against the live environment. Manual QA can be done here as well, because the pipeline pauses before approval on the next step.
   4. Requests a Github Environment Deployment to production, which requires manager approval. Once approved, this will do similar steps to 3.2:

      1. Creates and applies a patch, in case there have been updates to `main` since the testing image was created
      2. Builds and publishes an image with the patched code, tagged with a new production version number
      3. Updates the prod k8s manifest, setting the new production image
      4. Deploys the updated k8s manifest, deploying the new image to prod
   5. Deletes the `{branch-name}.example.com` environment in the k8s manifest and deploys it, removing the deployment preview
   6. Merges the pull request into main (this can only be done by the Github Action)
   7. Deletes the feature branch

### Strategy 2: Separate CI and CD pipelines, deploy with merge

This strategy separates the CI and CD into 2 separate pipelines. The trigger for the production deployment is a merge into `main`, rather than approval on a Github environment deployment.

1. Developers create features branches from `main`
2. When ready, developers create a pull request from their feature branch back into `main`
3. On `pull_request` triggers, Github Actions runs a CI/build pipeline that does the following:

   1. Runs CI checks (linting, static analysis, unit tests)
   2. Builds and publishes an image tagged with the branch name and its code
   3. Creates a k8s manifest for a new environment named after the branch, containing the new image
   4. Deploys the new k8s manifest, creating an environment available at `{branch-name}.example.com`.
   5. Runs functional tests and dynamic analysis against the live environment.
4. A manager merges the pull request. On `push` triggers to the `main` branch, Github Actions runs a CD pipeline that does the following:

   1. Builds and publishes an image with the code in `main`, tagged with a new production version number
   2. Updates the prod k8s manifest, setting the new production image
   3. Deploys the updated k8s manifest, deploying the new image to prod
   4. Deletes the `{branch-name}.example.com` environment in the k8s manifest and deploys it, removing the deployment preview